# How to suspend Java program from the server side when it is running at Unix box with the Eclipse remote debugger connected to JVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, unix, suspend

I'm using Eclipse remote debugger connected to the JVM running my application at the Unix box. I can easily suspend/resume remote application from the Eclipse. My question is how can I achieve the same from the back-end side?

Let's say that there is a certain trigger or condition only back-end is aware of. Once trigger has been detected I want to instruct JVM to suspend in order to enable myself to examine current program state using debugger in Eclipse at my workstation.

Comment: Any reason to not use conditional breakpoints in eclipse to achieve the same, i.e whatever condition you want to check on back-end can be specified in eclipse itself, right?

Comment: Vikdor is correct - a conditional breakpoint is the way to go

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion! I think that conditional breakpoint can address my situation However, the trigger/condition I've mentioned earlier is not something my app is aware of. I can make my app aware of it and then set conditional breakpoint. Initially I was looking for something like what "Suspend" does on the client side - it just suspends all threads at any arbitrary point in time on user discretion. I guess it is just impossible to achieve from server side without letting my app know about the trigger and setting conditional breakpoint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use conditional breakpoint in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194326/how-to-use-conditional-breakpoint-in-eclipse)