# Debugging Skip to a step in for loop

Tags: eclipse, debugging, for-loop

Considering debugging through a for loop

The length for this loop is just used for demo purpose

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    //do something
    //something more
    //something more
}
```

how do i skip to Xth iteration i would want to test : in this case if i want to test what happens when `i=567`.

is there any way by which i can have eclipse halted precisely at `i=567` in this loop ?

I am debugging over many `for` loops which run over varying large lengths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use conditional breakpoint in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194326/how-to-use-conditional-breakpoint-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to Debug Perspective.Go to Break point view.  Select the break point and enable hit count and enter hit count as 567.

[image]