# No checkbox for conditional breakpoint in eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I used to be able to set a watchpoint, or conditional breakpoint like the second answer here: [How to use conditional breakpoint in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194326/how-to-use-conditional-breakpoint-in-eclipse)

However the conditional breakpoint checkbox is not even there anymore... how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you dont seem to be able to set conditions on lines that are before the constructor. Finding a way around that wasn't hard, ofc. :)